# Embedd HTML code from PHP variable

Tags: php, html, embed

After more than 3 hours searching in google, I found that ppl do the other way around of what I am doing but anyway, here is what I want to do:

I have a variable **$location** which contains an HTML code (embedded google map code) i.e.

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"  
        marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/ms?........in a larger 
        map></iframe>
```

now in a php code, how can i get the map to be displayed?
the following outputs the HTML code as text

```
<?php echo $loation; ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You spelled your variable name wrong `$loation;` - should be `$location;`. Assuming you set your variable correctly like `$location = '...';`, you should be fine. Can you please post the code where you set the variable?

Comment: lol, you are right, it is $location, and thanks for the hint, it was defined as $info['location']; while it should have been html_entity_decode($info['location'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

Comment: Posted my comment above as an answer so you can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled your variable name wrong `$loation;` - should be `$location;`. Assuming you set your variable correctly like

```
$location = '...';
```

OR using [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax:

```
$location = <<<STR
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0"  
        marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/ms?........in a larger 
        map></iframe>
STR;
```

you should be fine.